# Tree implementation in .NET Entity Framework Core is causing reference issue

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, tree, entity-framework-core

I am using the following `Tree` class:

```
public class Tree
{
     public Tree() {}
        
     public Guid TreeRootNodeId { get; set; }
     public virtual Node TreeRootNode { get; set; }
     public virtual List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

with the `Node` implementation:

```
public class Node
    {
        public Node() {}

        public Guid TreeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tree Tree { get; set; }
        public Guid? LeftNodeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Node LeftNode { get; set; }
        public Guid? RightNodeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Node RightNode { get; set; }
    }
```

To setup up Entity Framework Core (EF) I used:

```
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Tree>()
  .HasMany(e => e.Nodes)
  .WithOne(e => e.Tree);

modelBuilder
  .Entity<Tree>()
  .HasOne<Node>(e => e.TreeRootNode)
  .WithOne(e => e.Tree)
  .HasForeignKey<Tree>(e => e.TreeRootNodeId);

modelBuilder
  .Entity<Node>()
  .HasOne(e => e.LeftNode)
  .WithMany();
            
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Node>()
  .HasOne(e => e.RightNode)
  .WithMany();
```

For performance reasons I want to store the `TreeRootNode` for each `Tree` to not always need to query all `Node` objects to access the root.

The issue: when I run the migrations EF the following exception is thrown:

```
Cannot create a relationship between 'Node.Tree' and 'Tree.TreeRootNode', because there already is a relationship between 'Tree.Nodes' and 'Node.Tree'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.
```

I added a new foreing key `TreeRootNodeId` to the `Tree` object. Looking at it from a database level I don't see any issue in having a FK point to a specific `Node` which is my root `Node`. But it seems EF has limitations.

Is there a way to configure EF to allow that design? If not is there a performant work around?

I already added a boolean to the `Node` which indicates if the `Node IsRoot`. But this is causing performance issues in the long run.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need a `Tree` reference in `Node` class?

Comment: From any (leaf) ```Node``` I want very quickly access to the root without traversing the ```Tree```  (possibly using a recursive query). So my plan is to go from any ```Node``` to the ```Tree``` and from there directly the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should add properties for keys (`Tree` and `Node` classes).

Something like this:

```
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

The problem is that you cannot reference to `Tree` property in `Node` class multiple times. When you set both columns, EF Core cannot identify which property should be used to fill `Tree` property (leaf or root).

You should add another property for `Tree` instance. `Node` class:

```cs
public virtual Tree RootOf { get; set; }
```

and then change model creating code:

```cs
modelBuilder
  .Entity<Tree>()
  .HasOne<Node>(e => e.TreeRootNode)
  // it was: .WithOne(e => e.Tree)
  .WithOne(e => e.RootOf)
  .HasForeignKey<Tree>(e => e.TreeRootNodeId);
```

Property `TreeId` of `Node` class becomes now nullable. After it you will have 2 types on nodes in DB:

- with `TreeId` (it is leaf)
- null `TreeId` (root of some tree)

Also I recommend add property `RootOfId` to node to see the root of which tree it is.

**UPDATE**

I paste the final classes:

```cs
public class Tree
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TreeRootNodeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TreeRootNodeId))]
    public virtual Node TreeRootNode { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? TreeId { get; set; }
    public Guid? LeftNodeId { get; set; }
    public Guid? RightNodeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(LeftNodeId))]
    public virtual Node LeftNode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(RightNodeId))]
    public virtual Node RightNode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TreeId))]
    public virtual Tree Tree { get; set; }
    public virtual Tree RootOf { get; set; }
}
```

And `OnModelCreating` method:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Nodes)
        .WithOne(x => x.Tree);
}
```

Comment: `RootOf` can be omited if you don't need it. The main trick is to make `TreeId` nullable.